# SQL update query linked to a control on a form

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

In the query below, i would like to update the field named 'ID' in table tblDependencies03 with a value coming from the field 'ID' in table tblDependencies01.   On my form I have a control named ID to allow me to identify which record in Table tblDependencies01 I would like to retrieve.   Strangly however, this query works however creates a record (with the correct ID number in the ID column) but duplicates it for every record in the table tblDependencies01 regardless of what the ID number is.  For example, if my control reflects record ID 96, and three records exist in table tblDependencies01 with ID 95,96 & 97, my end result in table tblDependencies03 will be 3 records created, all with ID '96'

Below is my code:

```
st_sql = "INSERT INTO tblDependencies03([ID])SELECT '" & ID & "' FROM tblDependencies01 WHERE [tbldependencies01].[ID] = ID "
```

Application.DoCmd.RunSQL (st_sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition in your SELECT is wrong.
Check your SELECT part of your query, and you will probably get more than one record. I also think that you don't really need any SELECT because you already have the value you are looking for. You can use VALUES:

```
st_sql = "INSERT INTO tblDependencies03 ([ID]) VALUES ('" & ID & "')"
```